[MS-WCCE]: Windows Client Certificate Enrollment Protocol - Null Signature
MS ADCS is using Windows Client Certificate Enrollment Protocol for issuing and renewing certificates. In the [MS-WCCE]: Windows Client Certificate Enrollment Protocol document, there is a chapter 2.2.2.6.5 Null Signature containing the following:
In CMS and CMC certificate request formats, the PKCS #10 request specified in the TaggedRequest field (see section 3.2.1.4.2.1.4.1.3) can contain only a null signature with the following signature field values:

signatureAlgorithm (see section 4.2, [RFC2986]) would be set to a hashing algorithm such as "Sha256" (OID 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1).
signature (see section 4.2, [RFC2986]) contains only the unencrypted hash octets computed over the DER encoded certificationRequestInfo component (see section 4.2 of RFC2986) using the hash algorithm specified in the signatureAlgorithm field.

Clients can send a PKCS #10 request with a null signature when the PKCS #10 request is specified in the TaggedRequest field in the CMS and CMC request formats as specified in sections 3.1.1.4.3.1.3, 3.1.1.4.3.2.2, 3.1.1.4.3.3.3, 3.1.1.4.3.6.1, and 3.2.1.4.2.1.4.1.1.
If the signature validation fails in section 3.2.1.4.2.1.4.1.1, then the CA MUST also check for a null signature and return a nonzero error to the client only when null signature validation fails as well. CA MUST check for a null signature only when the PKCS#10 request is specified in the CMS and CMC request formats as specified in sections 3.2.1.4.2.1.4.1.3, 3.2.1.4.2.1.4.2.2, 3.2.2.6.2.1.2.1.2, and 3.2.2.6.2.1.2.2.
From my understanding, this approach removes the Proof of Possession of private key from the PKCS#10 request allowing to impersonate literally any identity using the Null Signature. Administrator, or anyone able to request for the certificate in ADCS will be able to issue certificate based on any public key.
What is the purpose of Null Signature? Maybe I do not fully understand it, and I am wondering if this type of request that is allowed and described in MS-WCCE is secure at all.
The CMS or CMC request structure will not protect anyone to submit their public key and issue certificate from ADCS. Or am I wrong?

As it is an adversary can also request a certificate with their own key pair. Of course you would want to validate the information in the certificate and possession of the private key is a logical step in the validation process, but I'd think that e.g. the server name is more important. The bigger problem is that an adversary could replace the public key in transit, but usually a secure channel is required anyway. Possession of the private key can also be checked afterwards - although that would require revoking an already issued cert if it fails.
